# In kile, is it possible to Google search a selected text string?

Tags: kile

For a project I'm working on currently, I need to go through a large bibtex file, checking each of the references.  Thus I need to Google search each item.

My current method is:

1. copy title,
2. open a new browser window,
3. paste title,
4. search.

It seems to me that there could be a more efficient method.  Many packages these days admit a "select text/right-click/search in Google" feature, which would save me time.

Is there such a feature (or a similar feature) in Kile?

Comment: If appropriate, you could (also) ask the author(s) of the references to directly include urls for the references, e.g. DOIs. This would not only make your work much easier, but would also be quite helpful for the readers.

Comment: At the moment there is no feature implemented. So I voted to close. You can write a feature request to the maintainer.

Comment: A feature request does not make a good question here: closed I'm afraid.